# Deleting parentheses from string using regex

Tags: php, regex

Hi,

I am trying to delete [] parentheses with whats inside of them from string in php.

Input: "Hello [string] world!" , expected output: "Hello  world!"

What I tried is:

```
 `ereg_replace("\[[^\]]*\]","",$sres);`
```

Where $sres is the string I am trying to clean up. This should work imo and for some weird reason it does little bit. It actually replaces "[1]" with "", but it does not replace for example "[edit]", nor "[""]" and so on. I even tried to wrap the regex in / / :

```
`ereg_replace("/\[[^\]]*\]/","",$sres); `
```

But this didnt work at all, not even on that "[1]". I would be very helpful for any help.

Comment: Are you just trying to delete all square brackets from a piece of text?

Comment: it' s consfusing. Post a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: Agreed. "delete [] parentheses with whats inside of them" is the same as "deleting ALL square backets"

Comment: Added input and expected output. I do realise now I  have written that little bit confusingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use preg_replace.

```
preg_replace('~\[[^\]]*\]~', '', $sres);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xG2pF2/2)

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I´ve been searching web, but couldn´t find anything actually working. And not even some useful regex manual.

Comment: your regex is correct, a little bit study on preg_replace would help you.

Comment: Your code produces `"Hello  world!"` with his sample text. Note that there are two spaces between hello and world. Not sure if the OP cares or not though. :)